# how to lock a file on Windows from Haskell?

Tags: windows, haskell

I'm porting a program to Windows that uses POSIX fcntl locking (setLock, getLock, waitToSetLock). I can't see to find any locking stuff for Windows in GHC's libraries or on Hackage. Is there anything?

Answer (score 1):

I had the opposite problem when running the Idris REPL, that on Windows files are always locked when opened by the standard Haskell I/O functions, so files that are opened in the REPL can't be opened by an editor at the same time. So if you don't need a lock on a closed file your problem may already be solved.